# How can I do a text find and replace with a standard batch file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, find-and-replace

Without any additional tools, using just the command line that comes with Windows 7, how can I create a batch file that will perform a file and replace of some text in a file?

Answer (score 1):

This post from Stack Overflow has the answer for Powershell: [PowerShell Script to Find and Replace for all Files with a Specific Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837785/powershell-script-to-find-and-replace-for-all-files-with-a-specific-extension).

This [article](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_replace.htm) also explains how to search and replace text with Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Powershell 2.0 comes with Windows 7, so you can use this code snippet:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\File.ext"

ForEach-Object ($str in $file) 
{
  $content = Get-Content -Path $str
  $content | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "the the", "the"} | Set-Content $str
}

$file
```

Comment: Taken from http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_replace.htm

Comment: Indeed, I should mention such things in the future. :-)